# Do I have to apply changes before refresh in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, refresh

I have made changes to a huge table in query editor. Afterwards I have just used `Closed` as opposite to `Close & Apply`. Do I have to press `Apply changes` and then `Refresh` to have a full refresh? Or does just Refresh suffice? Does `Refresh` make both `Apply changes` and `Refresh` table?

With a huge table applying changes takes a few minutes and then refresh another a few minutes.

What are the tips for making changes to huge fact tables in query editor to minimize the load (or double load) at the stage of designing model?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you only press Refresh, it gets your data once more.

The (Close) & Apply, applies the changes to your model and refreshes the data.

You can even have a situation that you make a change in the query (model) so your constraints on data is different, this might conflict with your existing data. This is annoying because you cannot Apply the change anymore, you first need to ensure you filter/correct your data in the query side before you apply the changes.

Comment: So you say that I have to Apply first and then Refresh. So double data reading of couple of milion rows. No way around?

Comment: Indeed, no way arround. What I normally do is create the query with test data so I do not have the millions of rows but only like 50k

Comment: Be aware that when working with the query editor, you do not need to wait until all is loaded.